# ASP Razor importing namespaces into CSHTML file (Not MVC)

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-webpages

I am not using MVC, just "web pages". I would like to import the System.Collections.Generic namespace into a CSHTML file, but I can't figure out the correct syntax for it. Says it cannot find the namespace, attached image for error.

[image]

Edit: it seems specifically HashSet is missing from the System.Collections.Generic namespace, but only in my ".cshtml" files. The ".cs" files in my project are able to use it fine.

[image]

Comment: Is it really possible to use Razor _without_ MVC?

Comment: @UweKeim yes you can

Comment: @Jared what versions Razor are you using, Also its working in my views.. but its in a MVC project, not sure if that is making a diff. doubt! it but worth mentioning

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried prefixing it?

i.e. System.Collections.Generic.HashSet

Answer (score 0):

Fixed when I changed the Target Framework version from 4.5.2 to 4.5. Also fixed some problems I had with the System.Linq namespace missing.